# Unable to apply hover state to HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table

That's my CSS for styling up the HTML table. I guess something is messing the hover state.

```
.tg {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border-spacing:0;
  border-color:#ccc;
}

.tg td {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #ccc;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color:red !important;
}
```

Since I don't get the desired effect of having a red background while hovering the line. Here's the HTML:

```
<table class="tg">
  <tr class='tr-031e'>
    <th class="tg-031e"><b>№</b></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"><b>Name</b></th>
    <th class="tg-031e"><b>Age</b></th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='tr-031e'>
    <td class="tg-031e"><input type='checkbox' name='person'></td>
    <td class="tg-031e">Guy</td>
    <td class="tg-031e">18</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this,

```
tr:hover td { background-color:red; }
```

Comment: cool, didn't even know you could put something after the `hover`. plus, now the headers don't become red when you hover them, which I presume was an unwanted side-effect in the first place. Very nice.

Comment: @myfunkyside headers do turn red

Comment: @imbondbaby - that's weird, they're not for me (http://jsfiddle.net/hSYHv/), and really they couldn't since they are not adressed by the selector

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
tr:hover, td:hover {
    background-color:red;
}
```

**EDIT**

In `.tg td`, remove:

```
background-color: #fff;
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SkXc8/)**

Comment: That colors only individual rows. I need the whole line colored.

Comment: What if he wants to keep the tds with a background color, see my answer. A little more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

`<td>`s exist on a layer on top of the `<tr>`, as a result, your `background-color: white` is covering up the red.

```
.tg {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border-spacing:0;
  border-color:#ccc;
}

.tg td {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 10px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #ccc;
  color: #333;
}

tr {
      background-color: #fff;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color:red !important;
}
```